# Given a matrix $X$, what are all matrices $Y$ such that $X^TX = Y^TY$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X = USV^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ a matrix and its (compact) SVD decomposition.

Assume $X$ is of rank $r > 0$.

I am looking for all matrices $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times m}$ such that $Y^TY = X^TX$.

Clearly, given any orthonormal matrix $W \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$, the matrix $Z = WSV^T \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times m}$ satisfies $Z^TZ = X^TX$.

My question is, are these all the possbile $Y$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since $SV^T$ has full row rank, $Y=WSV^T$ for some square matrix $W$, and $W$ must be orthogonal because
\begin{aligned}
W^TW
&=S^{-1}V^TVSW^TWSV^TVS^{-1}\\
&=S^{-1}V^TY^TYVS^{-1}\\
&=S^{-1}V^TX^TXVS^{-1}\\
&=S^{-1}V^TVS^2V^TVS^{-1}\\
&=I_r.
\end{aligned}